# Images covered with random black squares in ms word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Microsoft Word document with images in it.

These images have formulas but I cannot see them because they're covered with random black squares.

Somehow the images are been corrupted. I know that they were ok at the beginning because I created the file myself.

I tried opening the document in many ms word versions and saving the document with different formats.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions to remove that black squares and see what's under?

**Edit:**

- **[Find document "Trabajo de sintesis.doc" here](https://www.we.tl/t-Rgaiu2heDf)**
- **[Virus Total analyze results here](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/901432986f07c60762611ac3bb073f3ae61164245b909c2354e4d149c9417602/detection)**:

Comment: Check other similar documents to see if this also happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I oppened other documents with images embedded and there are no problems. It might be related with the program I used then for the equation and graphics calculations, that I cannot even remember its name as it was so long ago, but coud be mathematica https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica. The documets I oppened images are not imported or added from Mathematica. I dont have a second similar document to check in that regard.

Comment: You might be missing a font that is used in the document, or the viewer mistakes the font. Try other viewers, also try on another computer. If you would like us to have a look, post the document somewhere. Otherwise, you will need to redo the equations.

Comment: That also was a good suggestion. I tried in 3 computers in total. 2 with win 10, one with win 7, with different word versions. Still the same problem. In case it might be of any help, it might have been done in win XP with word 2000 or 2003. Here you can find the document: https://we.tl/t-Rgaiu2heDf

Comment: Your document is missing a font called Mathematica1Mono. That would certainly affect any WMF (Windows Metafile) or EMF (Extended Metafile) images that used it. I don't know where you can get it as I suspect newer versions of Mathematica do not use it. You can find which fonts have been "substituted" in Word 365 by opening the documet and going to Word->File->Options->Advanced->Show Document Content->Font Substitution...

Comment: @yokki You should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @yokki thats right. As explained below I can at least manually remove the undesired characters to get to see equations below. Thank you

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the suggestion - until the OP responded I couldn’t be sure the font substitution was the problem, then most of the necessary material ended up in the answer.that was posted. Perhaps better to try to “improve” that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the same corruption in your document using Office 2019.
Word insists that the equations are images.

It seems that you need the original product with which you created these equations
for them to be displayed correctly.
This might or might not work for later versions of the product (Mathematica?)
and of Word.

I suggest re-doing the equations doing only Word, so the document will stay editable
in the future.
See the Microsoft article
[Write an equation or formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/write-an-equation-or-formula-1d01cabc-ceb1-458d-bc70-7f9737722702).

Comment: I was not able to unload mathematica fonts. However if you left click on the image and click on "modify image" (or similar in english, my ms-word is in spanish), all the images over the equations appear. They're lots of images of random characters that once erased the equations can be seen below. I though it was kind of screen shot, but as you said those are special images handled by word. Saw lots of people having problems with the mathematica fonts so damn them for not using standard ones. Thanks a lot for your help